# vagrant: Run shell script in Virtualbox after Docker instances boot (ordering is wrong)

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have the following setup with Vagrant.

- A Mac laptop running Yosemite.
- Inside of the laptop, an Ubuntu trusty64 instance managed with Virtualbox.
- Inside of the Virtualbox Ubuntu instance, two Docker containers, one of which runs Postgres and one of which runs Redis.

I would like to execute commands in the following order:

1. Boot the Virtualbox Ubuntu instance.
2. Boot the Docker containers.
3. Start the Docker containers.
4. Run a command on the Ubuntu instance.

I need the command to run last because I'd like it to interact with the containers. Here is what I have right now in my Vagrantfile - we're using the multi-machine configuration. I have omitted some of the `forward_port` details because they seem irrelevant to the order in which Vagrant runs provisioners.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "./docker-Vagrantfile"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |p|
    p.vm.provider "docker" do |pd|
      # ... 
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "redis" do |r|
    r.vm.provider "docker" do |rd|
      rd.name = "redis"
      rd.image = "redis"
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the linked `docker-Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "trusty64"
  config.vm.provision "docker"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/init_app.sh"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    # ...
  end
end
```

No matter how hard I try I cannot get `init_app.sh` to run *after* the Docker containers start running.

I also read that Vagrant executes provisioners in an "outside-in" order, so I tried a lot of shenanigans with trying to nest the `"shell"` provider inside of a `config.vm.define "foo" do |blah| ...` call, with no luck.

I believe maybe the Docker containers aren't being started until after all of the provision steps are done? Eg there's some post-provision step that's being called. In which case, I would *never* be able to run a script in a provisioner and have it run after the Docker containers are listening on their respective ports.

Answer (score 2):

you can have a look to the [vagrant trigger](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) it can be handy.

Even though its not documented from the main page, there is a `run_remote` command that can be used

```
config.trigger.after :up do
  run_remote  "bash ./scripts/init_app.sh"
end
```

Your script will be run after `vagrant up` has run so the docker containers should be ready

Comment: It looks like a good option to use plugins, but in this case that plugin has a build error. I don't know if it is a good idea to use it. =0)

Comment: Weird maybe you should open a ticket on this project or detail the error cause it should work